# How to determine if 3 html pages (panes) are fully refreshed?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My page has 4 panes (separate html pages), the last pane does some action upon refreshing of previous 3 panes. For example, the last pane says "LOADING" while the previous 3 panes are refreshing. The code looks like the following

```
//some event trigger
$.get(...., function(res){
  $(#pane1).html(res);
});
$.get(...., function(res){
  $(#pane2).html(res);
});
$.get(...., function(res){
  $(#pane2).html(res);
});
```

What I tried so far:
1) declare a global variable `refreshcount = 0`
add `.done(...)` after each `.get()`, in `.done()` I can add

```
function() {
  refreshcount++;
}
```

after all the `.get()`, check if `refreshcount == 3`, if so then get remove `"LOADING"` text in pane 4 and then reset `refreshcount`.

This will involve some while loop to check the state of `refreshcount`, which is heavy on the page.

Is there anything else in html, javascript, jquery I can do? I am very new to these, so there are definitely things I am not aware of. Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at "jQuery.when" function: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a master Deferred with [$.when](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) and attach a [$.then](https://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) callback to it like so:

```
$.when(
    $.get(...., function(res){
        $(#pane1).html(res);
    }),
    $.get(...., function(res){
        $(#pane2).html(res);
    }),
    $.get(...., function(res){
        $(#pane3).html(res);
    })
).then(function() {
    $(#pane4).html("Done loading!");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
var counterOfLoaded = 0;
var totalToBeLoaded = 3;
var testIfLoaded = function() {
  if (counterOfLoaded === totalToBeLoaded) {
    $(#pane4).html("Done loading!");
  }
};
$.get(...., function(res) {
  $(#pane1).html(res);
  ++counterOfLoaded;
  testIfLoaded();
});
$.get(...., function(res) {
  $(#pane2).html(res);
  ++counterOfLoaded;
  testIfLoaded();
});
$.get(...., function(res) {
  $(#pane3).html(res);
  ++counterOfLoaded;
  testIfLoaded();
});
```